AngularJS $http stops working after using cordova-plugin-advanced-http on iOS
I built an app by using Cordova and it's in production for more than years. Recently I had to install cordova-plugin-advanced-http to handle a request which returns a 302 Found status without redirecting automatically. It works fine but on iOS after this request is made, then whenever I try to use AngularJS' $http module it doesn't work, it says that $http is undefined.
If I skip the cordova-plugin-advanced-http request, $http works normally. I've only been able to reproduce this problem in iOS, for Android it's working well.
